# How to write a BigQuery left join without a condition of equality

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm moving a load of code from MySQL into BigQuery, and a number of our current reports reference the date dimension in order to count the number of weekend and holiday days between a start and end. I've looked at a lot of other answers on here and the main suggestion seems to be to use a cross join but I've spend half a day or so playing with different ways of doing that, and just can't quite make it work because of the logic around different dates? I've put the core piece of code below - can anyone suggest the best way to port this to BigQuery? I keep getting the error of "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join"

```
Date Table Layout:
dateKey int
fullDate date (dd-mm-yyyy format)
isHoliday tinyint
isWeekend tinyint
```

... and many other fields not relevant to this query. One line for every single date from 1950 to 2200.

```
select
    purchaseOrders.orderID,
    purchaseOrders.orderExpectedDate,
    purchaseOrders.orderDeliveredDate,
    purchaseOrders.orderCompletedDate,
    (dateDelivered.dateKey - dateExpected.dateKey) as daysLate,
    count(distinct dateExcluded.dateKey) as daysToExclude
from 
    `warehouse.purchaseOrders` as purchaseOrders
    inner join `warehouse.dim_date` as dateExpected
        on date(purchaseOrders.orderExpectedDate) = dateExpected.fullDate
    inner join `warehouse.dim_date` as dateDelivered
        on date(purchaseOrders.orderDeliveredDate) = dateDelivered.fullDate
    left outer join `warehouse.dim_date` as dateExcluded
        on (     (dateExpected.dateKey < dateDelivered.dateKey
                        and dateExcluded.dateKey >= dateExpected.dateKey
                        and dateExcluded.dateKey < dateDelivered.dateKey)
                or (dateDelivered.dateKey < dateExpected.dateKey
                        and dateExcluded.dateKey >= dateDelivered.dateKey
                        and dateExcluded.dateKey < dateExpected.dateKey)
                )
        and (dateExcluded.isHoliday = 1 or dateExcluded.isWeekend = 1)
```

Obviously table names have been changed for simplicity, and we apply various conditions on this main block to limit the date range of purchase orders considered, and it's also used in a very similar way for tables other than purchase orders, but the "dateExcluded" bit of SQL is used widely in many reports so I need to work out the best way to replicate this!

Thanks in advance

Comment: definitely cross join and move your condition from ON to where.

Comment: Thanks @AlienDeg, I was really hoping someone would have some wizardry to avoid this as it will be soooo messy but looks like I'll have to just take the hit :-(